# How to store values (entry) from WPForm Wordpress to PhpAdmin database

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my problem ! I have a website with Wordpress and i'm selling items with WPForms lite editions. There is 1 form with every client's information that i need to put into my SQL database.

When a client completed a transactions successfully, WPForm as a Entry with all information i need put but i'm not able to transfer this information to my SQL database!

My Wpform information looks like this :

- Invoice ID
- Full name
- Email
- Purchase
- Unit Price
- Quantity
- Subtotal
- TPS
- TVQ
- Total
- Billing information
- Agent Number
- Payment Information (stripe)

I've looked through this code......and i'm not sure what's what in this. It seems every ID of my single WPForm will be put into a value...?? but how is it suppose to go into my databse? Need explanation !

```
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'process_entry', 5, 4 );
function process_entry( $form_fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

global $wpdb;
$form_id = $form_data['id'];
$entry_data = array(
    'form_id'         => $form_id,
    'status'          => 'publish',
    'referer'         => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
    'date_created'    => current_time( 'mysql' )
);

// Insert into wpforms_entries custom table.
$success = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpforms_entries', $entry_data );
$entry_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

// Create meta data.
if ( $entry_id ) {
    foreach ( $form_fields as $field ) {
        $field = apply_filters( 'wpforms_process_entry_field', $field, $form_data, $entry_id );
        if ( isset( $field['value'] ) && '' !== $field['value'] ) {
            $field_value    = is_array( $field['value'] ) ? serialize( $field['value'] ) : $field['value'];
            $entry_metadata = array(
                'entry_id'   => $entry_id,
                'meta_key'   => $field['name'],
                'meta_value' => $field_value,
            );
            // Insert entry meta.
            $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpforms_entrymeta', $entry_metadata );
        }
    }
}
```

}

All i want is to transfer my WPForm information value to SQL database (phpadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Trying this instead and.....still no getting anywhere with it. My Databse is already connected to my wordpress and yet i'm not able to anything to it.

```
function Formsql( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {
  global $wpdb;
    $body = array(
        'InvoiceID'                => '',
        'FullName'                 => $fields['1']['value'],
        'Email'                    => $fields['2']['value'],
        'Purchase'                 => $fields['3']['value'],
        'UnitPrice'                => $fields['4']['value'],
        'Quantity'                 => $fields['5']['value'],
        'SubTotal'                 => $fields['6']['value'],
        'TPS'                      => $fields['7']['value'],
        'TVQ'                      => $fields['8']['value'],
        'Total'                    => $fields['9']['value'],
        'BillingInfo'              => $fields['10']['value'],
        'AgentNumber'              => $fields['11']['value'],
        'Payment'                  => $fields['12']['value'],
    );
    $request = wp_remote_post($wpdb->prefix . 'Vente', array( 'body' => $body ) );
}
  add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete_4427', 'Formsql', 10, 4 );
```